# How does the function work in replace js?

Tags: javascript

[image]

Before returning the function, it will perform 3 actions:
1- set the lower case of the letters of the received text,
2- find what needs to be replaced (non-whitespace characters that are at the beginning or after a space),
3- set the upper case of the first letters of words.

The syntax for an arrow function with an argument looks like this: `let func = (arg1, arg2, ... argN) => expression`, without an argument: `let func = () => expression`. But in the third action of the titleCase function there is an arrow but there are no parameters and brackets. Explain in detail how it works

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Also helpful: [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)